# GroupBy count on weekly in pandas with other columns

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a df as shown below, which is accident registered in an area.

```
Sector   RaisedDate   Inspector_ID    Priority  
SE1      02-Aug-2019  ID1             High
SE2      04-Aug-2019  ID1             Low
SE2      06-Aug-2019  ID2             Medium
SE1      12-Aug-2019  ID1             High
SE2      11-Aug-2019  ID1             Low
SE1      13-Aug-2019  ID2             High
SE1      18-Aug-2019  ID1             Medium
SE2      21-Aug-2019  ID1             Medium
SE2      20-Aug-2019  ID2             High
SE1      23-Aug-2019  ID1             High
SE1      25-Aug-2019  ID1             Low
SE2      29-Aug-2019  ID2             High
SE1      25-Aug-2019  ID1             Low
SE1      25-Aug-2019  ID2             High
```

From the above I would like to prepare below dataframe

```
Sector  #_Week1  #_Week2  #_Week3  #_Week4   #_Week5   No_of_High   No_of_low
SE1     1        2        1        4         0         5            2
SE2     2        1        2        0         1         2            2
```

where #_Week1 = Number of accident registered on week 1 (01-Aug-2019 to 07-Aug-2019 inclusive)

#_Week2 = Number of accident registered on week 2 (08-Aug-2019 to 14-Aug-2019 inclusive)

#_Week3 = Number of accident registered on week 3 (15-Aug-2019 to 21-Aug-2019 inclusive)

#_Week4 = Number of accident registered on week 4 (22-Aug-2019 to 28-Aug-2019 inclusive)

#_Week5 = Number of accident registered on week 3 (29-Aug-2019 to 31-Aug-2019 inclusive)

No_of_High = Total number of High priority accident in that sector for all data.

No_of_Low = Total number of low priority accident in that sector for all data.

For that I tried below codes and that does not work

```
df.set_index('RaisedDate').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Weekly')).Sector.count()
```

Comment: Doesn't that work? Where are you going wrong?

Comment: Weekly is not acceptable in parameter. Try `'7D'` and see if it works.

Comment: Your data starts on Aug-02-2019. Is there are reason to start grouping on `Aug-01`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using what @Parth said and adding `"Sector"` to the `groupby()`:

```
print(df.set_index('RaisedDate').groupby([
    'Sector',
    pd.Grouper(freq='7D'),
]).Sector.count().unstack())

RaisedDate  2019-08-02  2019-08-09  2019-08-16  2019-08-23
Sector                                                    
SE1                  1           2           1           4
SE2                  2           1           2           1
```

Gets you a little closer to what you want. You could then rename the columns to match your output.

I also notice that I have values `4` and `1` in my week 4 and don't have a week 5. Not sure if that's a problem for you?

---

To add on the High/Low prority columns you could join a new dataframe with different groups.

```
# store the weekly groups
date = df.groupby([
    'Sector',
    pd.Grouper(key='RaisedDate', freq='7D')
]).Sector.count().unstack()


# rename columns
date.columns = [f'week{i}' for i in range(1, len(date.columns)+1)]

# store the priority groups
prio = (df.groupby([
    'Sector',
    'Priority'
]).Priority.count().unstack().drop(columns=[
    'Medium',
]))

# join them
print(date.join(prio))

        week1  week2  week3  week4  High  Low
Sector                                       
SE1         1      2      1      4     5    2
SE2         2      1      2      1     2    2
```